# How do I add bootstrap classes to elements in tinymce

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tinymce

I am building a blog where I use TinyMCE

When I use TinyMCE, my output is:

```
<p>test</p>
```

Whereas I want it to be:

```
<p class="myclassfrombootstrap">test</p>
```

Where for each element, a proper class from bootstrap is chosen as default. If I have to, I can manually edit a file so that the classes are added by default.

I've googled for a bit now, but I can't figure out how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.